# Documentation for a function inside an environment

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have the following code:

```
envir = environment()
envir$a = function(x) x+1
```

is there a good way to document the function `a` in a way that when I call `?envir$a` it will show its documentation?

Comment: Are you documenting the `envir` object?  If you goal is specifically to get it to work with the `?` operator I don’t think you can. But you could create a help page with some other name

Comment: I can document `envir` as well. Could you give a simple example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the `?htmltools::tags` help page. In that package `tags` is a list with a bunch of functions defined like `tags$p()` and `tags$div()`. They are all documented on a common page that's really called `?builder`.  But that package also exports all those functions as top-level functions so `all.equal(tags$p, p)` is TRUE. You can see how they do that in the github: https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/main/R/tags.R#L674

Comment: Thanks! Gonna take a look.